# How to use CanCan with gem controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancan, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I've spent a while trying figure out the best way to authorize a controller that's from a gem with CanCan. I'm specifically using [Comfortable Mexican Sofa](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa). I have it all setup with Devise and CanCan but having trouble authorizing specific controllers from within Comfy. The closest thing I can find similar to what I'm after is in the [Fortress CMS gem](https://github.com/melvinsembrano/cms-fortress/blob/master/lib/cms/fortress/rails/engine.rb).

I've tried using initializers and engines to extend `before_action` and write a simple auth method. The only thing I can find for CanCan and Comfy is [here](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/wiki/Devise-Cancan-Authentication-Authorization), but it's only addressing site login not specific controllers like pages, blogs, etc.

Basically, it comes to down - how am I able to extend a gem controller so I can authenticate a user for that controller specifically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the [initializer](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/blob/master/config/initializers/comfortable_mexican_sofa.rb#L114-L133) you could customize your own authorization logic:

```
# Uncomment this module and `config.public_authorization` above to use custom public authorization
module ComfyPublicAuthorization
  def authorize
    # TODO: your own authorization logic. Check params variable here
    true
  end
end
```